# A characterization of absolutely continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$. I'm trying to prove below result mentioned as *Theorem 5.2* in my lecture [note](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/TA2011-gradient-mei11.pdf) of gradient flows.

> **Theorem** A map $F:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ is [absolutely continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099894/the-definition-of-absolute-continuous-function/4100439#4100439) if and only if there is a $\lambda$-integrable $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ such that
> $$
> \int_a^x f \mathrm d \lambda = F(x)-F(a) \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
> $$
> In that case, $F$ is differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. and $F'=f$ $\lambda$-a.e.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof**

- Let $F$ be absolutely continuous. Then $F$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606242/an-absolutely-continuous-function-has-bounded-variation) of bounded variation. Then $F$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609955/the-lambda-integrability-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-of-bounded-variation?noredirect=1&lq=1) differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. and its derivative $F'$ is [$\lambda$-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Let $G(x) := \int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda$. Then $G$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610637/let-f-in-l-1-lambda-and-fx-int-ax-f-mathrm-d-lambda-then-f-i) absolutely continuous. So $G-F$ is absolutely continuous. By Lebesgue differentiation [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610584/a-simple-proof-of-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-for-dimension-1), $G$ is differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. and $G' = F'$ $\lambda$-a.e. It follows that $(G-F)' = 0$ $\lambda$-a.e. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610621/if-f-is-absolutely-continuous-and-f-0-lambda-a-e-then-f-is-constan) $G-F$ is a constant. On the other hand, $G(a)=F(a)=0$. So $G=F$.
- Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be [$\lambda$-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space) such that
  $$
  \int_a^x f \mathrm d \lambda = F(x)-F(a) \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
  $$
  Let $G(x) := \int_a^x f \mathrm d \lambda$. Then $G$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610637/let-f-in-l-1-lambda-and-fx-int-ax-f-mathrm-d-lambda-then-f-i) absolutely continuous. Then $F =G + F(a)$ is absolutely continuous. By Lebesgue differentiation [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610584/a-simple-proof-of-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-for-dimension-1), $G$ is differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. and $G' = f$ $\lambda$-a.e. On the other hand, $F'=G'$ $\lambda$-a.e.